# How to run Procfile with multiple commands on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, procfile

I'm trying to deploy the static website to Heroku and I struggle how to correctly setup the `Procfile`.

I have next command to run on the server:

- `npm install`
- `gulp build` (will make a build with `/public` folder)
- `http-server` (will serve `/public` by default)

---

What I've tried:

- `web: npm install; gulp build; http-server`
- `web: npm install & gulp build & http-server`

Comment: Procfile is not the correct place where you should trigger the build steps, instead, use some customised buildback. It would be better if the site building generating is done elsewhere then in Heroku example use some CI tool(CircleCI etc). Currently after every restart, the Procfile command would run and start the install process.

Comment: @RistoNovik thanks for your comment, I've just solved it out and posted an answer :) I've tried to keep it simple as much as possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay, so I've spent a bit of time on that and came up with the answer. By default, heroku is installing all packages from the `package.json` file, so `npm install` is no longer required. Then what was left - `gulp build` and `http-server`.

For that case, I've added `"postinstall" : "gulp build"` to my `package.json` and it left me with `web: http-server`.

Simplifying things have actually solved the problem. Not sure how useful that information might be to you, but it's worth to share.

Comment: For what it's worth you can also use heroku-postbuild in case you already use postbuild locally or somewhere else, e.g. `"heroku-postbuild": "vue-cli-service build"`

Answer (score 5):

You may also have been looking for `&&` or a library like concurrently.

Regardless, and per the docs, use `Procfile` as nothing more than an entry point to your npm start script.

---

Use the npm scripts lifecycle as stated [(npm-scripts)](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

## Directly From The Documentation [(heroku-build-process)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process).

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "mocha",
    "postinstall": "bower install && grunt build"
}
```

Heroku has adopted the 'there's an app for everything' mantra, but for buildpacks. Whatever you're building, there's a buildpack for it.

Comment: You should include the necessary code and details in your answer, not just as links

Answer (score 3):

You can run multiple command inside **Procfile** using `sh -c` command :

```
worker: sh -c 'firstCommand && secondCommand && etc...'
```

Notes : **Procfile should be at the project root level**.

For example :

```
worker: sh -c 'cd backend && yarn install && yarn build && yarn start-worker'
```

Or in your case (if u have Procfile at the same level as package.json) :

```
web: sh -c 'npm install && gulp build && npm run http-server'
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.